# How to quit from 'auto' block in gitbook ?

Tags: latex, gitbook

I am new to gitbook . As I have started writing books in gitbook , I am facing some problems . The following issues are needed to known to me :

1) I can write mathematical equations in gitbook using katex/latex . For example , I can write the following equations in gitbook :

```
$$\frac{1}{2}$$
```

After this code , a fraction is appeared as 1/2 . This works fine at the time of editing . But at the time of reading , no fraction is appeared. Only the above code is shown . How to get escape from this problem ?

2)  If I want to position an equation/image or whatever , I am surprisingly observe that that image is gone and instad a code is appeared .

After googling , I have come to know that a code block will be appeared if I keep 4 spaces or a tab spaces .

So what should I do if I want to keep an equation or an image at center ?

3)  [I am editing my book in this url :](https://www.gitbook.com/book/sultanoid/hsc-math-2nd-paper/edit#/edit/master/README.md?_k=w3d3o2) . From which url , will i read my book ?